# Setting index values of first list as elements of second list

Tags: python

I have 2 lists, one has unique values and the other has repeating values from the first list, I want to modify the second list to contain index positions of the first list as the new values.

`list_2` should be `[0, 0, 2, 1, 0]`

This is the solution I have but I was wondering if it could be done in 1 line, in `list_2` without creating a new list.

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['a','a','c','b','a']


# new should be [0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
new = []
for i,j in enumerate (list_1):
    for i in list_1:
        if i in list_2:
            new = [list_1.index(p) for p in list_2]
```

Comment: You tagged this as `numpy`, could do `(a == b[:, None]).argmax(1)` if all elements are in the second array

Comment: Why the numpy tag? The question does not related to numpy

Comment: @Valentino, my bad, fixed it. had added the tag cause my original dataset is a NumPy array so was aiming for responses in numpy as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a dictionary out of values and indices in `list_1` then use this dictionary as look up for the values in `list_2` and call `dict.get` for each values in `list_2`, you can do this in a List-Comprehension:

```py
>>> list_1_dict=dict(zip(list_1, range(len(list_1))))
>>> [list_1_dict.get(v) for v in list_2]

[0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```

The advantage of creating look up dictionary is you won't have to go back to the list again and again to find the index of particular value which is often less efficient vs getting a value in dict has `O(1)` complexity. Also, `dict.get` returns `None` if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this except if a value in list_2 doesn't exist in list_1 you'll get ValueError:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['a','a','c','b','a']

new = [list_1.index(c) for c in list_2]

print(new)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: wow, we've got the same solution, hahaha

Answer (score 0):

how about this list comprehension method?

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['a','a','c','b','a']
new = [list_1.index(p) for p in list_2]
print(new)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```